# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Tags: python, django, tuples

i got this problem :

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

my script is :

```
def destroyVM(request,id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('testDB')
    c = conn.cursor()   
    api = 'http://196.203.216.18:5555/client/api'
    apikey = '3U7UPLR4JHYEzOhKe0JYnR_ICChdmuynnl0SdqmFzFgG4Hgd6BJHHjcSk2K3SsXUvheLEoN-SlRuEOpqZbqbVA'
    secret = 'JU1gQk99VpAEZWWKxiR97w8mIPtSZsXwuORL6H2NKkve0EHDvBZ5IQN-CXHqMhVKmOLRcRhjyr4RPnTqAmD5Ig'
    cloudstack = CloudStack.Client(api, apikey, secret) # ouvrir une connexion serveur/client
    c.execute("SELECT vmid FROM vmm_vm where id ="+id+";");
    conn.commit()
    vmid = c.fetchone()
    vm = cloudstack.destroyVirtualMachine({'id':vmid})

    c.execute("DELETE FROM vmm_vm WHERE id = '"+id+"';")

    conn.commit()

    conn.close()

    return render_to_response('vms.html',{'vms':Vm.objects.all()})
```

is the problem in vmid ? when I fetch the query 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Cursor.fetchone`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) returns a sequence (a tuple for your case) that represent a row.

You need to extract item from the tuple.

```
vmid = c.fetchone()[0]
```

or using tuple unpacking:

```
vmid, = c.fetchone()  # same as (vmid,) = c.fetchone()
```

Comment: The second code snippet will still throw a ValueError, if there's too many values on the right side.

Comment: @Shashank, According to the query `SELECT vmid FROM vmm_vm where ...`, the tuple will contain only one item.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I didn't look at the query carefully. +1